# Is this a valid interpretation of probability?

Tags: probability

Let's say we have the following statements:

- consider a fair dice, with 6 sides
- the probability of rolling any given number from $1$ to $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$

Now the second of these statements is just a reformulation of the first. They contain exactly the same information.

But is this generally true of questions of probability? In other words, even though it can be much more complicated to work out the probability of a given outcome, is the correct answer still just a restatement of the original facts?

I have always had trouble with the interpretation of probability, because explanations of it always involve discussions of things like expectations and frequency, which always seemed to be to be empirical and/or subjective, and not very mathematical.

But this interpretation doesn't attempt to tell us what will happen, or what to expect; it only tells us about the relative apportionment of the various possibilities. In other words, it's the same information we started with, in a more useful form. Just like when you re-arrange an equation into a more useful form.

So I would like to know, is this valid, and if so then where does it lie in the spectrum of popular interpretations of probability?

Comment: The case you mentioned is called the "Laplacian case" in which every elementary event has the same probability. This simplifies the calculation of probabilities drastically, because we only have to count the events. We can safely assume that anyone speaking of a "fair dice", means a dice satisfying the Laplacian case.

Comment: *"But this interpretation doesn't attempt to tell us what will happen, or what to expect"* - but it does. How can you deduce statement 2 from statement 1? Only because you already know that in statement 1, by the word "fair" you really mean that the probability of each side is the same. Statement 1 is not really any less specific, it just pretends to be.

Comment: @JackM I'm taking "fair" as a given. In other words "if a 6-sided dice is fair, then the probability of rolling any given number from 1 to 6 is 1/6". I'm suggesting that this is all that's involved in any question of probability; i.e. restating the original given information in a more useful format.

Comment: @JohnB "Restating the original information in a more useful format" sounds to me like a description of *mathematics* in general. But what exactly do you mean? Can you give an example of a more complex probability problem where you're not as certain of your interpretation?

Comment: @JackM Great question, and no I can't give you an example. But I'm aware of things called "subjective" and "frequentist" interpretations of probability, and I don't understand them. So instead I'm trying to come at it from the other side - in other words, what's *missing* from my understanding, such that I *need* a different interpretation?

Comment: It's not clear to me from reading your post what "my understanding" refers to in the question "what's missing from my understanding".

Comment: After reading up based on @Peter's comment and thinking some more, I now realize that the problem with my interpretation is that it relies on a circular definition of probability. I think that is the real motivation for complicated interpretations.